# OAuth from script

Tags: ruby, oauth

I've seen a few questions/guides about implementing 3 step OAuth inside of a Rails app, but I'm interested in only the client side part of it. I'm trying to authenticate as a consumer to an OAuth2 server.  As far as I can tell, I'm building the access token correctly.

```
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(@config[:client_id], @config[:client_secret], 
{
  :site               => "http://api.server.com",
  :oauth_version      => "2.0",
  :http_method        => :post,
  :authorize_path     => "/oauth2/authorize",
  :access_token_path  => "/oauth2/token",
  :request_token_path => "/oauth2/request_token"
})
token_hash = { oauth_token: @config[:client_id], oauth_token_secret: @config[:client_secret] }
@access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(@consumer, token_hash)
```

All of this succeeeds, the access token ends up looking like this:

```
#<OAuth::AccessToken:0x007fb6f2290468 
  @token="client_id", 
  @secret="secret",
  @consumer=#<OAuth::Consumer:0x007fb6f2290800
              @key="client_id",
              @secret="secret",
              @options={:signature_method=>"HMAC-SHA1", 
                        :request_token_path=>"/outh2/request_token",
                        :authorize_path=>"/oauth2/authorize", 
                        :access_token_path=>"/oauth2/token", 
                        :proxy=>nil,
                        :scheme=>:header, 
                        :http_method=>:post, 
                        :oauth_version=>"2.0", 
                        :site=>"https://api.server.com"
                        }
            >, 
  @params={:oauth_token=>"client_id", 
           :oauth_token_secret=>"secret"
}>
```

The problem is that any request I make using `@access_token` returns a `Forbidden` error.

Any ideas what part of my request is wrong?

Comment: did you get your request_token? debug it and show more infos in your question

Comment: I used this guide http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/OAuth_Ruby_Tutorial which seems to indicate not needing to get the request token when you aren't trying to make requests on behalf of another user, which I'm not.

Comment: in that artical, `Two-Legged OAuth` is only for you making a request from API Consumer to Justin.tv directly, with no user involved. and `Three-Legged OAuth` It requires that you get a Request Token and put the user through the step of authenticating you on the Justin.tv site,  you said any request is return s `Forbidden`, so I think you may try `Three-legged OAuth` and get request_token

Comment: There should be no user interaction here.  It's for a gem I'm building.  If I use the `Three-Legged OAuth` then I have to deal with a browser, which I can't do with this application.  Is my understanding of it not correct?

Comment: That's the point, `The JTV API also uses Two-Legged OAuth to allow applications to sign requests`, if you can only use `Two-Legged OAuth`, you must figure out whether your oauth server support `Two-Legged Oauth`